# Is there a way to vectorize struct(:).a(:,1) to array(:,:)?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have the following code that I am interested converting from a `for` loop to a vector operation, if possible.  The premise is that given a structure array `data`, each element has a field `a` which contains a single column vector.  All column vectors over all fields `a` are the same length.  I would like to take each column vector from all fields and transform the data into a matrix where each column contains one column vector from a field `a` in this array.  This means that the first column should be `data(1).a`, the second column should be `data(2).a` and so on.

```
    % All arrays in 'data.a' are column vectors of equal length
    % (leaving 'numCols' in incase some genius can also make that general)
    [numRows,numCols] = size(data(1).a);

    % Pre-allocate for speed
    array1 = NaN(numRows,numCols);

    % Convert from struct to array
    for ii = 1:length(data)
        array1(:,ii) = data(ii).a;
    end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup.  Just do:

```
array1 = [data.a];
```

This is nice because you don't even need to know the size of a column vector or the total number of columns this would produce in order to build a matrix for pre-allocation (the total number of columns actually equal to just the total number of elements in your structure array btw).  In fact, pre-allocation is no longer required as we are building the matrix directly.  You are simultaneously creating the right amount of space and populating the matrix with contents in one step.  This is because we are exploiting the fact that `data(ii).a` contains a single column and all columns for the field of `a` in your structure array contain the same amount of rows in the column vector stored in field `a`.

Doing `data.a` outputs what is known as a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html).  This means that doing `data.a` is equivalent to typing out the following in the MATLAB command prompt:

```
>> data(1).a, data(2).a, data(3).a, ..., data(N).a
```

If you placed `data.a` within a set of square braces, you would essentially be building the matrix you seek one column at a time.

## A reproducible example

```
>> rng(123); clear data;
>> data(1) = struct('a', rand(5, 1));
>> data(2) = struct('a', rand(5, 1));
>> data(3) = struct('a', rand(5, 1));
```

`data` contains a three-element structure array with a field `a` that contains a random `5 x 1` column vector.

Here's what each vector looks like:

```
>> for ii = 1 : numel(data), disp(data(ii).a); end

0.6965
0.2861
0.2269
0.5513
0.7195

0.4231
0.9808
0.6848
0.4809
0.3921

0.3432
0.7290
0.4386
0.0597
0.3980
```

Using the single-line of code I gave you gives:

```
>> array1 = [data.a]

array1 =

    0.6965    0.4231    0.3432
    0.2861    0.9808    0.7290
    0.2269    0.6848    0.4386
    0.5513    0.4809    0.0597
    0.7195    0.3921    0.3980
```

Comment: thanks for your help.  I never new about comma separated lists, but that explains a lot of confusion I've had in the past.  One thing - I didn't quite follow your first paragraph.  In the first sentence, were you basically saying that you don't have to worry about preallocation?  It seems at odds with your second sentence about exploiting the symmetry of my fields. Also, in the parenthesis, does "number of elements" correlate to `struc(numberOfElements)`?  I've never quite made myself familiar with the vocabulary for discussing structure size.

Comment: You're welcome. Comma-separated lists are very useful. You certainly have to worry about pre-allocation, but because we are building the matrix directly, no pre-allocation is required. I actually didn't say that you don't have to worry about pre-allocation in general, but for this case it is not required to think about that topic. I apologize if this was unclear. The result using comma-separated lists is the completed matrix.  Pre-allocation is only used if you are intending to modify the contents of the array in a loop.  Because you aren't looping anymore, there is no need for pre-allocation.

Comment: Also, "number of elements" is simply the length of your structure array.  You have `N` elements in the structure array, right?  Each element contains a single column vector... so would you agree with me that the total number of columns is simply the total number of structure elements, `N`?  In this case, `numCols = length(data);` where `length(data) = N;`.

Comment: BTW, I've edited my post slightly to avoid the confusion you encountered.

Comment: I expected yesterday's solution to work in the following circumstance, but it doesn't.  This time `a` is an array and I want to take the same column from each `a`.  Any ideas?

`% The field 'a' is an m-by-n array, the same size for all elements in 'data'`
`array2 = [data.a(1:100,3)]`

Instead of an `array2` with column n equal to `data(n).a(1:100,3)`, I get the error `Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 2 results.`.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize comments do not accept line breaks, so it's pretty unreadable.  There should be a line break between `'data'` and `array2`.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't escape a loop here. Doing `data.a(1:100,3)` is the same as `data(1).a, data(2).a, ..., data(N).a(1:100,3)`. What you did is a bit counter-intuitive but that's the way it is.  There is an alternative where you can concatenate all of the matrices together as one big matrix, then subsample the correct amount of columns.  Something like `array1 = [data.a]; array1 = array1(1:100,3:size(data(1).a,2):size(array1.2));`  This subsamples every third column of each matrix concatenated in the larger matrix and returns the result. Unfortunately, this needs a larger amount of memory.